# Shifting Division issue in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

using shr but only working when I am using shift for count 1 for not working. . . . only division by 2 is working but when exceeding the things are not going well.
here is the e.g code :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
num db 8
.code
main proc
mov ax , @data
mov ds , ax

mov al , num
shr al , 2 ; this instruction is giving the error   
mov dl ,al 
add dl , 48
mov ah ,2
int 21h

mov ax , 4c00h
int 21h

main endp
end main
```

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. Shifting right by 2 bits means division by 2^2 that is 4. So the result is 8/4=2 and that is printed by your code.

Comment: @Jester this is correct ! when i try shr al , 2 or more count , , it is not worn=king

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez but its given invalid instruction operator error

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez giving the same error !

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez MASM611 ! 
yea error on line !

Comment: yes i am sure very sure

Comment: Also paste the exact error message and clarify whether it is a compile or run time error.

Comment: Paste it in your question, I need to see it (screenshot).

Comment: My problem has been resolved @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez  thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the 8086, the SHR instruction can shift right one place with `shr al,1`, or it can shift multiple places with `shr al,cl`. So if you want to shift right two places, you either write two shift instructions:

```
shr al,1
shr al,1
```

Or you put the value 2 into cl and shift:

```
mov cl,2
shr al,cl
```

Later Intel processors (I don't recall if it was the 80286 or 80386) added the `shr al,x`, where `x` can be a number other than 1.

If you're getting that error at compile time (i.e. the assembler is issuing an error), then it's telling you that the instruction is not valid for the processor you've selected to generate code for.

If you're getting an illegal instruction at runtime, it's because the assembler generated code for a later processor (an 80386, for example), but you're running the code on an 8086, which doesn't support that instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Some assemblers accept :

```
shr ax, 4
```

Other assemblers require to use CL :

```
mov  cl, 4
shr  ax, cl
```

Also test if SHR requieres 8 or 16 bit register :

```
shr  al, cl          ;<==== THIS MIGHT BE REJECTED.
shr  ax, cl
```

It depends on the assembler you are using. Next two links help:

http://www.masmforum.com/board/index.php?PHPSESSID=8d46cd4ecb1688be429ab49694ec53e6&topic=12565.0;wap2

http://people.sju.edu/~ggrevera/arch/references/MASM61PROGUIDE.pdf

Comment: `shr ax,4` is not a valid instruction on the 8086. If an assembler accepts that instruction when generating 8086 code, the assembler has a bug.

Comment: That's why I said "Some assemblers", I didn't mention any processor type.

Comment: Jose, how many processors have an AX register? Of course you meant an x86 assembler, especially since this is tagged "x86". And on x86, `shr ax,4` is simply illegal and an x86 assembler won't accept it.